# Context Menu in JxBrowser only shows up once

Tags: jxbrowser

I'm following along the example from 
[JxBrowser-Examples](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-Examples/blob/master/spellchecker/src/main/java/SpellCheckSuggestions.java) to show context menu in my JxBrowser web app. However, this popup only shows once, and it never shows up again.

My step is to right click anywhere inside the Java Swing app, and context menu shows up as see in the following screenshot, [image: context menu screenshots] 
And I right clicked again and again, and **context menu never shows up again**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ShowContextMenuCallback.Action::close` whenever the menu goes away. In the example they call `tell.close()` in the [implementation of `popupMenuCanceled`](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-Examples/blob/master/spellchecker/src/main/java/SpellCheckSuggestions.java#L119) but they also call it [after performing each action](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-Examples/blob/master/spellchecker/src/main/java/SpellCheckSuggestions.java#L78). In my implementation I found it easier to just call `close()` in the implementation of `popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible`.